# mute/unmute android device from PC

Tags: android, desktop-computer, remote

I have 2 phones, one private and one work phone.

I want to be able to send some sort of trigger from my PC to mute/unmute both phones.

I've tried IFTTT with mail, but it's working VERY slow and laggish for me. In the long run I intend to create a python-script that I can run to instantly mute/unmute both phones.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: "In the long run I intend to create a python-script"  - sounds to be a programming problem, you might get better answer on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @MátéJuhász I don't need help with the script, I need help figuring out what tools to use. I only included that info so I wouldn't get answers like "Use AirDroid"

Comment: "what tools to use" is also off-topic, asking for product recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance of achieving that using **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** on the android device.
Tasker can be programmed to do *tasks* triggered by *events*.

- **Scenario 1**:

  In this case the triggering event could be an SMS with an specific *keyword* to mute and another to unmute.

  Program **Tasker** to mute the phone on reception of the keyword by SMS. Now you only need an interface to send SMS from PC.

  Most carriers enable an *email address* associated with your phone line. So, for example sending and email to `13052617778@txt.att.net` will send and SMS to `13052617778`.
- **Scenario 2**:

  *Tasker* + *Pushbullet* + *PushTasker* on the Android device.

  [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) is a system created to send data (text, URLs, pictures) from PC to Mobile and viceversa. You can send from the web interface that they provide, but also from the free [API](https://docs.pushbullet.com/) that lets you create your own scripts (Python, bash, PHP, etc.).

  Send a Push from the web interface or from your own script, it is intercepted by PushTasker in the android device and redirected to Tasker that will mute/unmute your phone.

Install Tasker and tinker at it. As it can detect a lot of events maybe you could devise a better scenario than the two I proposed.